# Cannot resolve reference to bean while setting bean property

Tags: java, spring, rest, cxf

Can you help resolving the below error as i am setting the REST example for the first time.
I am getting error while Tomcat 6 is started SEVERE:

> Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name'restContainer': Cannot resolve reference to
>   bean 'probablyPrimeSerivce' while setting bean property 'serviceBeans'
>   with key [0]; nested exception is
>   rg.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'probablyPrimeSerivce' is defined

My beans.xml

```
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
  xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
  http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs 
  http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd 
  http://cxf.apache.org/core 
  http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"> 

  <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/> 
  <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"/> 


   <context:component-scan base-package="com" />


  <jaxrs:server id="restContainer" address="/"> 
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans> 
    <ref bean="probablyPrimeSerivce"/> 
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans> 
 </jaxrs:server> 


</beans>
```

================================================

My ProbablyPrimeSerivce class

```
@Service("probablyPrimeSerivce")
@Path("/prime")
public class ProbablyPrimeSerivce {

@GET
@Path("/{number}")
@Produces("text/plain")
public boolean  isPrime(@PathParam("number") int number){
    return true;
}
}
```

====================================

[image]

Comment: Try <context:component-scan base-package="com.project.*" />

Comment: @Silviu Tried the above code but the same error

Comment: @Senthil try adding <context:annotation-config/>

Comment: @coder:Tried now adding the annotation config but no luck same error

Comment: If you define the bean manually in the xml, does it work? If it doesn't, then the xml content is not the problem, something else is causing the problem(maybe the xml is not loaded at all?)

Comment: Even after defining the bean manually there is a problem.I will check the eclipse and tomcat

Comment: Check the word (maybe) : probablyPrimeSerivce Serivce and Service